# Dependency Theory - Question

Tags: database, database-design, axiom, functional-dependencies, database-theory

I have been trying for the past few hours to get this, I have included below the only answer I have worked out that seems like it may go somewhere, can someone tell me if I am on the right tracks:

Question:

```
   Gamma =  { U-> PT….. 1 
Q-> SU……2
W->Q……….3
T->WV…..4
V-> R……..5    }>
```

`Q->WR`  holds

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[Augmentation (Axiom of Augmentation): If X → Y, then XZ → YZ (from Wikipedia)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms#Axiom_of_augmentation)

V -> R, hence WV -> WR

You said yourself, Q -> WV, therefore, Q -> WR by transitivity ?

Comment: yes from the working out i done Q -> WV is a dependency I came to but I don't know if I went about it in the right way. Do you think what you mentioned is all I am missing?

Comment: In the examples that have done in class there wouldn't directly be mention of decomposition in the solution, is there another way in how this can be derived?

Comment: I don't think so. Draw a directed graph of Gamma with the vertices Q, U, T, W, S, P, V and R and the arrows as directed edges, and you'll see that the shortest paths from Q to W and R are Q -> U -> T -> W and Q -> U -> T -> V -> R. You need all those rules, but the graph shows you the solution visually (Q functionally determines both W and R, therefore it also determines their union).

Comment: I didnt think the original way I had done it would of been right, I guess I was trying to find fault with it, thank for your help Archimedix.